# When rendering my object it is darker than the preview. How do I fix this

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

When looking at my object in preview it looks like this which is what I want

[image]

But when I render the object it looks like this

[image]

I have the scene world tab off because I tried looking for answers before posting and that's what I saw but it still shows up like this and I can't use viewport render because it shows the circles around the metaballs. And it's the same issue for my metaballs

Here is my Blender file:[image]

Comment: hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Looks like you are using shading Viewport Shading "Material Preview" that view has HDRI to let you see your materials with illumination. If you switch to Viewport Shading "Render Preview" you will see your scene darker because you have no lights [SEE](https://youtu.be/JM-Z4F3WtmI?si=31krYMBcWBbYTjVl&t=80). If that's not the case, make sure to add more information

Comment: Viewport render is a preview of your final render, you need add lights or an HDRI to light your scene, the reflection and light that you see on your first image is just to get an idea of your render, you must add lights or HDRI so you don't get a dark scene